# Program type already present: com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable

Tags: android, json, android-volley

[I used Volley v1.1.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pumvI.png)
Ive tried some way to solve just like use the older version, but nothing.

[This is my dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vdjm.png)

Comment: Could you please post your whole app-level `build.gradle` file?

Comment: I've add a pics sir @Jay

Comment: Could you please do a clean build once? If it doesn't solve the problem, try invalidating the cache and restart Android Studio(this option is in File menu bar). There's nothing wrong with the app-level build.gradle.

Comment: I just tried sir, but still not fixed

Comment: truely the problem is I put a volley file in my libs, so I deleted it. than the problem is solved, thanks mr @Jay